# Python logging causing latencies?

Tags: python, performance, logging, latency

I'm developing a real-time REST API using Python3+bottle/UWSGI. I was experiencing latencies in my code, sometimes 100s of ms, which does matter in my app.

Using `logging` module, I was trying to identify slow parts of my code, printing how long individual codeblocks took to run. I know this is an extremely poor way of profiling the code, but sometimes it is able to do the job quite well.

Even though I identified some slow parts, I was still missing something -- the individual parts seemed to take 10s of ms, but very often they took 100s of ms as the whole. After some increasingly insane experiments which drove me almost completely nuts, I've come to the following:

```
t = round(100*time.time())
logging.info('[%s] Foo' % t)
logging.info('[%s] Bar' % t)
```

Surprisingly, it gives:

```
2014-07-16 23:21:23,531  [140554568353] Foo
2014-07-16 23:21:24,312  [140554568353] Bar
```

Even though this seems hard to believe, there are two consequent `logging.info()` calls, and for some reason, there is a gap of almost 800 ms between them. Can anybody tell me what is going on? It is noteworthy that if there are multiple `info()` calls, the latency only appears once in the whole API method, most frequently at its very beginning (after first call). My only hypothesis are disk latencies, there are several (but not so many!) workers running simultaneously and I'm using rotational disk, no SSD. But I thought there are buffers and that the OS will do the disk-flush asynchronously for me. Am I wrong in my assumptions? Should I avoid logging completely to avoid the latencies?

**EDIT**

Based on Vinay Sajip's suggestion, I switched to the following initialization code:

```
log_que = queue.Queue(-1)
queue_handler = logging.handlers.QueueHandler(log_que)
log_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
queue_listener = logging.handlers.QueueListener(log_que, log_handler)
queue_listener.start()
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format="%(asctime)s  %(message)s", handlers=[queue_handler])
```

It seems like it works fine (if I comment `queue_listener.start()`, there is no output), but the very same latencies still appear. I don't see how is it even possible, the call should be non-blocking. I also put `gc.collect()` at the end of each request to ensure the problem is not caused by the garbage collector -- without any effect. I've also tried to turn off the logging for the whole day. The latencies disappeared, so I think their source must be in the `logging` module...

Comment: I would suspect a system problem and not a code problem. For instance if you're on ubuntu and have not defined a swap file or if you're on windows and you have less than 20GB on your hard drive, you'll experience loss of responsiveness

Comment: If you can reduce it to a small self-contained script which shows the problem, please post that. Otherwise, it can be hard to see what's going on in a multi-threaded environment. Can you be sure that there are no synchronous handlers defined *anywhere* in your system (e.g. in third-party libraries)? That could affect the latencies. Libraries are not supposed to add handlers other than `NullHandler`, but developers don't always do things as they should.

Comment: Also note, the `format=` parameter to `basicConfig()` only applies to handlers added in that call, i.e. to the `QueueHandler` in this case. That does not use a formatter, and the `StreamHandler` will not have a formatter set as it's only passed to the `QueueListener`. You would need to set a formatter on that explicitly.

Comment: @VinaySajip You are absolutely right, it is caused by the UWSGI "magical" forking of processes. When I printed the handlers currently used, ``QueueHandler`` is gone and the default ``StreamHandler`` is present again. I'm now trying to use lazy initialization to create the handler AFTER the the process is forked.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Try async logging provided by Logbook

As hasan has proposed, async log handler can be the way to go.

Recently I have tried using `Logbook` and can say, it will provide you all what you need for this - [ZeroMQHandler](http://logbook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/queues.html#logbook.queues.ZeroMQHandler) as well as [ZeroMQSubscriber](http://logbook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/queues.html#logbook.queues.ZeroMQSubscriber)

Comment: Honestly, 4 years later, we're running everywhere on Logbook based on your original advice, just didn't manage to write it in here :) It works great and the issue never appeared anymore, so your answer was right!

Comment: How does LogBook do async logging? I cannot find any information related to do that in their docs

Comment: @SarimMehdi LogBook ZeroMQHandler sends the log record to ZeroMQ socket and proceeds, actual writting of the log happens (if ever) asynchronously - if you use ZeroMQSubscriber which collects the records and does something with them.
Anyway, this async is by no means asyncio.

Answer (score 26):

You can use asynchronous handlers ([`QueueHandler`](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/logging.handlers.html#queuehandler) and corresponding `QueueListener`, added in Python 3.2, and described in [this post](http://plumberjack.blogspot.co.uk/2010/09/improved-queuehandler-queuelistener.html)) and do the I/O processing of your logging events in a separate thread or process.

Comment: Seems like it exactly solved my problem! I've just put it into production and the logging latencies seems gone. Moreover, I had to do only little programming to fix it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Oh no, it was too soon to exult, the very same latencies reappeared, so my problem remains unsolved :(

Comment: Finally, I've got everything implemented correctly, including lazy initialization of the logger AFTER the process is forked, and the latencies are really gone. Your answer was right from the beginning, it was just the messing with UWSGI which caused all the complications.

Comment: I experienced delays of 1 second on Windows (no such issues on Linux) when using the socket logging handler. This was resolved by using `QueueHandler` and `QueueListener` .

Answer (score 7):

First, start with an eviction queue (circle buffer) .... this ensures the queue handler cannot consume all available RAM.

```
class EvictQueue(Queue):
    def __init__(self, maxsize):
        self.discarded = 0
        super().__init__(maxsize)

    def put(self, item, block=False, timeout=None):
        while True:
            try:
                super().put(item, block=False)
            except queue.Full:
                try:
                    self.get_nowait()
                    self.discarded += 1
                except queue.Empty:
                    pass
```

Then replace all of the handlers at your root... whatever they are after normal configuration....

```
def speed_up_logs(): 
    rootLogger = logging.getLogger()     
    log_que = EvictQueue(1000)
    queue_handler = logging.handlers.QueueHandler(log_que)
    queue_listener = logging.handlers.QueueListener(log_que, *rootLogger.handlers)
    queue_listener.start()
    rootLogger.handlers = [queue_handler]
```

Effects:

- Logging will be very fast
- If you log faster than you can write to the drive, older unwritten entries will be  silently discarded.
- Might be nice to enhance this by logging a single entry with the number of discarded entries every minute or so (swapping discarded to zero).

Comment: There's a `break` command missing after `super().put(item, block=False)`

Comment: Hey Erik, good work and well done!. **6** months ago, @PhilippeRemy highlighted a very important caveat in your work, yet you turned a blind eye to it. Can we know why, please?

Answer (score 4):

It might depend on the logging handler. My experience is that e.g. PostgreSQL used as a logging handler is a very poor choice for speed. FileHandler might give you very good results but if your system is very I/O heavy then even simple file writes can be slow. I suggest to use some asynchronous handler, e.g. send the logs via UDP to a dedicated process.